Determine my position in a queue table (Can I check if a browser session is still active?)
I am trying to make a waiting queue for an e-ticket system.
I have 2 tables.

OrderSessions (in this table the active orders a stored)
WaitingQueue (in this table I store the sessions if OrderSessions contains more than xx records).

In my SystemTable I set the maximum of active OrderSessions, for example 2
So if a users wants to buy an e-ticket, I check if there are more than 2 session active. If so, I write the GuidID (sessionID), StartTimeQueue (and some other values) in table WaitingQueue.
Every 10 seconds I check if there are still 2 records in OrderSessions and I check the position of this session in WaitingQueue (where EndTimeQueue=NULL).
If OrderSessions.recordcount < 2 and position in WaitingQueue is = 1 then I store EndTimeQueue in table WaitingQueue and I add a record to OrderSession with the Guid. And the actual order-screen is shown to the user.
This all works fine... ;-) The user who is at the 1st position in table WaitingQueue
My problem:
When it's very busy with ordering tickets, the WaitingQueue contains a lot of records.
And very ofte a user closes its browser. But, the record still exists in table WaitingQueue.
My question:
Every active browser sessions "talks" to the server every 10 seconds. Is there a way the server can check if a session in the WaitingQueue is still active? Or is there any other way I can delete the record from the WaitingQueue when the user has terminated its browser?

You probably want some kind of websocket or similar which maintains the "Still Waiting" status, and the server can expire that if it's been too long since an update.
